# Hyperlink tag inside paragraph and text-align:center

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

```
<div style="width:400px">
  <p style="text-align:center">
    <a>
      <img src"..." />
    </a>
    Some text..
  </p>
</div>
```

So the goal here is to center the image inside the div. Text-align:center works on the images that are not inside the hyperlink tag, but once they are, it doesn't affect them, just the text.

I don't want to go with display:block and margin-left/right auto, simply because we'll need to align some pictures to the left and right using float.

Any ideas why the hyperlink prevents text-align to work?

Answer (score 0):

you also need to add `text-align:center;` for parent anchor to make image align center inside anchor link.

```
<div style="width:400px">
    <p style="text-align:center;">
        <a style="text-align:center;">
            <img src"..." />
        </a>
        Some text..
    </p>
</div>
```